# What is the meaning of the conjugate function of $f$ in $L^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I am wondering what the rationale is for defining $f^{*}=\|f\|_{p}^{1-p} \cdot \operatorname{sgn}(f) \cdot|f|^{p-1}$ is. Is there some geometric meaning or intuition that could lead me to see why this function was defined this way?

> **Hölder's Inequality**
> $$
> \int_{E}|f \cdot g| \leq\|f\|_{p} \cdot\|g\|_{q} .
> $$
> Moreover, if $f \neq 0$, the function $^{2} f^{*}=\|f\|_{p}^{1-p} \cdot \operatorname{sgn}(f) \cdot|f|^{p-1}$ belongs to $L^{q}(X, \mu)$,
> $$
> \int_{E} f \cdot f^{*}=\|f\|_{p} \text { and }\left\|f^{*}\right\|_{q}=1 .
> $$

Comment: Given $f$, setting $g:=f^*$ realizes equality in Hoelder's inequality.

Comment: @daw Is this the main intiution? Just that it happens to work for Holder's Inequality?

Comment: @Sam Was the answer below helpful? If so, please mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the intuition is algebraic. It would be very useful to know that for any $f \in L^p$, equality can be attained in Holder's inequality. So given $f \in L^p$, we seek $g \in L^q$ such that Holder's inequality is an equality. It suffices to consider $g$ with $\lVert g \lVert_q = 1$. A natural candidate is $g = C|f|^{p - 1}$, with $C \geq 0$. You can solve for $C$ and recover $g = |f^*|$.